# why there is a gap in the file name created using paste?

Tags: r, function, paste

I was trying to write a file using R and in order to distinguish each file, i tried to add a different suffix each time in a function.

For example......

```
    counts <- function(counts_file)
    {
     ..............................
     ..............................
     name <- substr(counts_file,1,5)
     file <- paste(name,".cpm.csv")
     write.csv(countpermillion, file)
     }
```

But when i run the function `counts("JKNC1.bam.tsv")`, the output file created is like this
`JKNE3 .cpm.csv` i.e there is a gap between the `JKNEE3 and .cpm.csv`. What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks
Upendra

Comment: have a look at `?paste`  It has a `sep` argument, short for "separator".  The default value for `sep` is `" "`

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked at this extra argument in the paste function..

Answer (score 3):

The default separator is a space. `paste(name,".cpm.csv",sep="")` should do what you want here. Alternately, you could use

```
paste0(name,".cpm.csv")
```

The documentation for this can be found by typing `?paste` at the console.

Comment: Both of them worked. Didn't realize that by default separator is a space with paste. Thanks...